# Audible Errors - Custom non-blocking text-to-speech handler for Python's logging module

Tags: python, logging, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech

I am building a screen-less Raspberry Pi-based long term art installation.
A common application of [Text-to-Speech on the Raspberry pi](http://elinux.org/RPi_Text_to_Speech_(Speech_Synthesis)) is folks configuring their Pis to speak their IP Address on boot to ease SSHing.

I have grown to love the logging module. Never again commenting out uncountable print statements makes my heart glow. For my situation, it would be ideal to have a logging handler that speaks the error message. The StreamHandler and the FileHandler I am currently using are great for development and post-problem diagnosis, but horrible for in situ problem solving. Also, there is something delightfully SciFi about my robot shouting errors at me.

[I found an example of a custom handler for SMS-based error logging,](http://pantburk.info/?blog=77) and tried to implement my own with e-speak. It speaks, but the entire program stops at the end of the first spoken sentence.

I am looking for advice on how to implement a stream handler that does not block the execution of the program.
**My broken custom handler:**

```
import logging
import os

#based on SMSHandler http://pantburk.info/?blog=77

def speak(stringToSay):
    '''say whatver it is told to say, squleching annoying warnings'''
    stringToSay = "'"+stringToSay+"'"
#English female voice, emphasis on capitals (-k), speaking slowly (-s) using direct text:-
#the 2>/dev/null' is there because any calls to the rPi audio card result in a dozen warnings.
#  see: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/errors-with-espeak
    os.system('espeak  -ven+f3 -k5 -s150 '+stringToSay+' 2>/dev/null')

class TALKHandler(logging.Handler): # Inherit from logging.Handler
        def __init__(self):
                # run the regular Handler __init__
                logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        def emit(self, record):
                # record.message is the log message
                speak(record.message)
```

**The snippet from the program that is logging:**

```
logging.handlers.TALKHandler = speechHandler.TALKHandler
# create the handler object
talkingHandler = logging.handlers.TALKHandler()
# Configure the handler to only send SMS for critical errors
talkingHandler.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
# and finally we add the handler to the logging object
logger.addHandler(talkingHandler)

ipAddress = [(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 80)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]
ipAddress = " ".join(ipAddress)
ipAddress = ipAddress.replace(".","dot")
logger.critical("Current IP Address is " + ipAddress  )
```

Comment: When you say "stops", do you mean the program actually exits? Or does it hang forever?

Comment: @dano It hangs forever.

Comment: Can you put a print statement after your `os.system` call, to confirm it's actually returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was asked ages ago - I missed it when it was posted and stumbled on it by chance. The following works for me:

```
import logging
import subprocess
import sys

class TalkHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        cmd = ['espeak', '-ven+f3', '-s150', msg]
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        p.communicate()

def configure_logging():
    h = TalkHandler()
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(h)
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def main():
    logging.info('Hello')
    logging.debug('Goodbye')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    configure_logging()
    sys.exit(main())
```

When I run it, I hear "Hello" and then "Goodbye" spoken.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks! I don't have an Rpi set up, but it works on my mac with the say command.